# Error deploying .war from Nexus to Wildfly 29.0.1.Final via Docker

Tags: java, docker, wildfly

I'm having an issue while trying to deploy a .war deployment from Nexus into Wildfly using Docker. The error message from the logs is as follows:

```
10:50:45,912 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "file.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".component.\"jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet and jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener disagree on InnerClasses attribute"}}
```

Versions being used:

Wildfly 29.0.1.Final
Vaadin 24.3.5
JDBC 11.2.0.jre17
Java 17

Additionally, here's a copy of my pom.xml file for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Shibbolet</id>
            <name>Shibbolet</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <groupId>grouId</groupId>
    <artifactId>file</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>file</name>
    <description>file</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.3.5</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.bmg.coreapi2</groupId>
            <artifactId>core2</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-release</id>
            <url> nexus_url (removed for privacy concerns)/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshot</id>
            <url> (removed for privacy concerns)/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                    <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
                    <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
                    <filename>${wildfly-filename}.war</filename>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>wildfly</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>file</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I would appreciate any insights into resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like Tomcat is pulled in and intereferes with WildFly: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/17773

Comment: I've added the latest dependency (vaadin-eventbus) along with its exclusions in the pom.xml, but I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: You might have servlet APi jar leaking in

Comment: You can check your dependency tree via `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: I did find org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:10.1.11 and I also excluded it from the dependency. 
but still getting the same error

Comment: Why are you running a server environment - spring boot - inside of a server environment - wildfly?  Spring boot is a standalone server environment based by default on top of Tomcat.  Wildfly is also a standalone server environment.  This is not the right way to do this.  Either user spring boot or use wildfly - not both.